# POST using HttpURLConnection timeouts from device but not from emulator

Tags: java, android, networking

I have a server which I'm doing GET requests fine **both** from emulator and from device(galaxy s2, 4.1.2).

But POST-ing from device throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://*.*.*.*:8080/MyProject/rest/order`which when I check on the server is a `SocketTimeoutException`

It timeouts even before my specified timeout(60 seconds)!

My POST code is as follows:

```
public String postOrder(String orderJSON, String uri) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        con.setConnectTimeout(2*TIMEOUT_VALUE);//TIMEOUT_VALUE=30000
        con.setReadTimeout(2*TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        // con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            out.write(orderJSON.getBytes("utf-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        String json = readStream(con.getInputStream());
        con.disconnect();
        return json;
    }

private String readStream(InputStream in) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Same is happening with Apache HTTP client:
Emulator Android Version: 4.1.2
Device Android Version:   4.1.2

```
public void postOrder(String orderJSON, String uri) throws Exception{
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(orderJSON);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
        int code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String codeString = String.valueOf(code);
        if(!codeString.startsWith("2")){
            throw new Exception("Server ERROR, httpCode; " + code
                    + ", response entity: "
                    + EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want a Read Time out and a connection time out ? That too at the same time ? What version of android are you using ? Can you try using 'HttpPost' instead of 'HttpURLConnection' and see what happens ?

Comment: Yes, same is happening! See my updated question